# Unable to forward the values form servlet to html

Tags: java, html, servlets, request

I am trying to Send userName as request to html page as set attribute, But it is not displaying  the msgs in FormDemo, Please let me know where i am going wrong.

Login page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="loginServlet">
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"/> <br/>
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Login servlet.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    // read form fields
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    System.out.println("username: " + username);
    System.out.println("password: " + password);
    request.setAttribute("userName", username);
         request.getRequestDispatcher("/FormDemo.html").forward(request,response);
}

}
```

FormDemo.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Form Demo</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <p> <%= request.getAttribute("userName") %></p>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
       <display-name>LexisNexis</display-name>
       <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>

           <servlet>
          <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
             <servlet-class>package.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
           <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
           </servlet>

           <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
             <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
             </servlet-mapping>

          <servlet>
          <servlet-name>DemoServlet</servlet-name>
               <servlet-class>package.DemoServlet</servlet-class>
           </servlet>

          <servlet-mapping>
               <servlet-name>DemoServlet</servlet-name>
               <url-pattern>/demoServlet</url-pattern>
             </servlet-mapping>

            </web-app>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a way to write values like this into a plain HTML page. You will need to use a [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info) to do this.

Comment: Yes adding " <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>" and made the page as JSP then it worked. Thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

U can not render values from servlet to html. Jsp tags you are using works with JSP only. JSP is also a type of Servlet so when you forward a request from one servlet to JSP, request bring all request and response data to JSP and your attributes will be available in JSP too. So use FormDemo.jsp instead of FormDemo.html. It will work then.