# Pass Java Object from servlet to HTML

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets

I have one html page "organization.html" and I want to get Java Object value into this html page.

My Java Object

```
public class User_Objects {
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}
```

My organization.html page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Organization</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var reqfirstName = '${reqObj.firstName}';
        alert("reqfirstName>>>>>>>"+reqfirstName);
        var reqlastName = '${reqObj.lastName}';
        alert("reqlastName>>>>>>>"+reqlastName);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="orgname" action="org_name" method="post">
        <div class="container-fluid orgdiv">
            <div class=" text-center topbgimage">
                <img src="images/bg.jpg" class="" style="max-width: 100%;">
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12  heading text-center" style="text-align: center;">
                        <h1 class="">Hello <label id="lblfullname"></label> </h1>
                        <p>Enter your organization Name to determine if there is a current terms of service agreement with app.</p>
                        <label><span class="starred">*</span>Oraganisation:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtOrgName" name="txtOrgName"
                        class=" form-group" placeholder="enter your organisation"
                        style="float: none; margin-left: 8px;" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-center footerdiv"
                style="text-align: center;">
                <input type="submit" name="btnOrgName" id="btnOrgName" class="bg-primary btn"
                    value="Validate" onclick="return validateOrg();" />
                <input type="hidden" name="myJObject" id="myJObject" value='${reqJSONObj}' />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

My Java code is given below

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(fillObj);
request.setAttribute("reqJSONObj", jObj);
request.setAttribute("reqObj", fillObj);
forward = "/organization.html";
RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
view.forward(request, response);
```

But When my organization.html page is loaded, I am getting `reqfirstName>>>>>>>${reqObj.firstName}` alert.
I am getting `${reqObj.firstName}` not value of `firstName` of `reqObj` Object.

I am using Java with Eclipse Mars1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to forward the values form servlet to html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591670/unable-to-forward-the-values-form-servlet-to-html)

Comment: Probably you need to use `.jsp` not `.html`.

Comment: Unless your server is set up to treat .html as ,jsp i.e. compile the "page" then this won't work. Try changing your filename to "organization.jsp"